# Spaces in File & Folder Names using Mod_Rewrite returns 404 or 500 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

Basically my rewrite rules work fine but if I am working with files or folder with spaces in them it doesn't work and just returns 404/500 errors.

For example:

```
RewriteRule !^test/ test%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /test/
RewriteRule ^test/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]
```

The above rule works perfectly fine. However if the file or folder has a space in it I would be using the following code:

```
RewriteRule !^test%20folder/ test%20folder%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /test%20folder/
RewriteRule ^test%20folder/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]
```

But this just returns errors! I have also tried to removed the %20 and just have a blank space and that also returns an error.

Anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use \s (regexp white space) to match it or One\ Word\ And\ Another if you know the full string.

In your case:

```
^test\ folder/(.*)
```